# CDI injection of bean from parent module to child module

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Question only about CDI beans, not EJB.

Is it good practice to develop architecture where you need to inject bean from parent module to child module?

For example I have three modules:

1. **common** - here i need to use some environment setting, but **common** doesn't know in which environment it will be executed, client or server (in my case it is packaged as a lib in a ear/lib directory and separately it is tested by java se client);
2. **client** - here I can provide settings from properties file for example (for testing purpose, it is not packaged in ear)
3. **server** - here I can provide settings from ejb configuration file (it is a ejb module in same ear as common).

So **client** depends on **common** and **server** depends on **common** (they extend and use classes from common) but injection goes in reverse direction. So @Inject injection point exists in **common** module, but producer methods in **client** and **server**.

Additionally to philosophical aspect I have a real question. Can I further inject bean from ejb.jar to ear/lib/*.jar or it will be impossible due classpath issues?

Regards

Comment: Mind to update your post with a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: it is minimal and complete question

Comment: Indeed, just regarding the "...injection goes in reverse direction...". Are you injecting components from server/client in common? That's the need for the example.

Comment: oo, i see, provided info in question body, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your deployment setup so I can only guess that the client and server are separately packaged with common not in the same EAR?
Also I do not understand what you mean by parent and child unless you copy the contents of common directly into your modules, or your modules extend common classes. 
It's not a good practice to have circular dependencies, it makes testing difficult and tightly couples your code. Common should not rely on having a bean in another module to function.

You can inject accross modules but they have to have their own beans.xml defined in meta-inf.

Comment: client.jar is for testing purpose, and it is not packaged at all. common.jar is a lib in ear/lib directory, server.jar is a ejb module. I am interested in cross-platform solution, so i didn't mention concrete app server.

Comment: anyway, you answer is very helpful

Comment: Although the jars in the EAR/lib directory are considered to be a single "module" for class loading purposes, classes in other modules (web, EJB, etc) are not normally accessible to them. Only the converse is true. ie. classes in other EAR modules can see classes in the EAR/lib directory.

Comment: Libs in WAR/lib can see every other class so it would be logical that the same applies for ears (meaning EAR/lib uses the same classloader as other modules and they can see eachother).
Edit: if its not automatically done you can either turn it on in the container or use a class-path entry in the manifest file (in wildfly like this: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)